# How to close batch (.bat) file after execution?

Tags: batch-file

I have written copy code as:

```
@echo xcopy F:/source/*.pdf H:/target /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
@echo off
```

I just want to close the CMD after the copy is done . `Exit` after copy is not working.

Comment: Your batch is copying nothing because of the `@echo` before `xcopy`. It' s just printing the whole xcopy-command to CMD. And CMD should automatically close in your case. Tested here and it's working fine. Is there more code you didnt supply?

Comment: And the directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as on Mac/Linux. So please use in directory/file paths the backslash character, for example `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe F:\source\*.pdf H:\target\ /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y`. __Note:__ The backslash at end of target path is very important and recommended on copying multiple files with `xcopy` as it makes clear for `xcopy` that the specified target is a directory and not a file name.